# How to send model data from view to api controller using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, api

I am trying to send the value from my this view to given API controller.It is working when i hard-code the json data.I am unable to send the data of id and brandname when i press the button since it is in table. How do I make it work?Please help

```
  <table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Brand.BrandName)
        </th>
                <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>

        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand.BrandName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
      <td><input type="button" id="Save" /></td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
@section scripts {
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Save").click(function () {

            var brand = { 'id':1, 'brandname': 'abc' }

            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:51429/api/brands',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: brand,
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.log('Error in Operation');
                }
            });


        });
    });

   </script>
    }
```

I have a brand API. And it post API controller is

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]Brands brand)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
        db.Brands.Add(brand);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = brand.Id }, brand);

    }
```

Comment: Try adding a `Content-type` header to your request for JSON: `application/json`. Also, serialize your data before sending: `JSON.strinigify(brand)` instead of just `brand`. Edit: setting content type in jQuery is adding a new field to the settings call: `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`

Comment: how do i add the id and brand name from model and send it to ajax from this view.

Comment: Since the data are in table so i cannot access its id or i dont know how to do it.

Comment: What is `Brands` and how does the resulting HTML code look like?

Comment: Brands is a model which has Id and Brandname. And after hitting save button from this view it passes only id and brandname to the post api.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to go about this. One would be to select the cells and extract the data to send it later on:

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
  var $button = $(this);
  var $cells = $button.closest("tr").find("td");

  var brand = {..., 'brandname': $cells.eq(0).html(), ...}

  ...
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this

Comment: cant get the value from var brand = {
                'id': $cells.eq(1).val(), 'brandname': $cells.eq(2).val()
            }

Comment: @Sres What does "cant get the value from" mean exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You are using DisplayFor, which is used to display the lable, or name of the text field. you need to replace DisplayFor with EditorFor where you are populating data in foreach loop.
Also you should use razor HTML helper form or AJAX helper form

Comment: Is it possible to use html helper form if the api controller is in different project?\

Answer (score 0):

There are different approaches to get controls values from views, one solution can be `wrap` the `<table>...</table>` with a `form` tag like

```
<form id="Form1">
<table class="table">
 <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Brand.BrandName)
    </th>
            <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
    </th>

    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Brand.BrandName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
  <td><input type="button" id="Save" /></td>

 </tr>
}

</table>
</form>
```

Access control values like

```
var brand = $('#Form1').serialize();

$.ajax({
     url: 'http://localhost:51429/api/brands',
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: brand,
     success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
          console.log(data);
     },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log('Error in Operation');
     }
});
```

Comment: But i only need id and brandname so serializing and sending all data is not right i think.